# idat.exe -S, path with spaces

Tags: ida, idapython, command-line

I'm trying to execute the command: `idat.exe -S"home\mypath to script\myscript.py args" -L"logs" -A mybin.so`

But I get an error. Among the logs is present the error:
`home\mypath: could not locate file -> OK`
meaning that the white spaces are not correctly handled. I attempted to include escaping (e.g. `"home\mypath\ to\ script\myscript.py"`) or additional quotes (`"'home\mypath\ to\ script\myscript.py' args"`) but no luck.

Do you know how to pass to idat.exe using -S a script in a path which includes white spaces? I'm using ida 7.6

Comment: How do you execute the command? In a cmd.exe terminal a powershell terminal, a lnk file?

Comment: I'm trying in powershell:

> `& "idat.exe" -S"home\mypath to script\myscript.py args" -L"logs" -A mybin.so`

Comment: Try `idat.exe -A -S"script path" "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3" -L"logs"`. That's how my Python code that runs IDA headless instances does it.

Comment: It works, thx!!

Answer (score 0):

Try `idat.exe -A -S"script path" "arg 1" "arg 2" "arg 3" -L"logs"`. That's how my Python code that runs IDA headless instances does it.